# Disqus analogs? (comments platforms)

Tags: javascript, comments, system

What analogs of Disqus for comments do you know?

Answer (score 2):

I know only IntenseDebate.

Answer (score 1):

Livefyre is another alternative to disqus (and IntenseDebate).